# How to get source code of a WebPage in Vala

Tags: webkit, vala

I'm trying to save the source code of a web page (after rendering) in vala using WebKit (I can use only *webkit2gtk-4.0* like package) but I'm able only to get the uri. Anyone know how to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Would the `WebView.get_snapshot` method do the job?

https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-4.0/WebKit.WebView.get_snapshot.html

Comment: Thanks, i found also a solution that use the WebKit.WebExtension with signal "page_created" (https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0/WebKit.WebExtension.page_created.html), then with WebPage (https://valadoc.org/webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0/WebKit.WebPage.html)  that it returned i can wait the rendering with "document_loaded" and then i can extract the source code with "get_document_element (). outer_html"